# Add count to the root elements using FOR XML PATH

Tags: sql-server, xml, for-xml-path

I have a Sql statement that returns xml of products in which root element is products. How can i add count attribute to the root element.

My sql is:

```
SELECT 
id AS 'product_id',
name AS 'product_name'
 FROM product
WHERE status = 1 AND ......
ORDER BY productid
FOR XML PATH('product'), ROOT('products')
```

Result is

```
<products>
   <product>
    .
    .
   </product>
</products>
```

I want to change result to

```
<products count="100">
   <product>
    .
    .
   </product>
</products>
```

Comment: you have to just add count =100 or you want to take a actual count from xml the it should appear in count= ?

Comment: i want to take actual count of products

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*) AS '@count',
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM product c1 FOR XML PATH('product'), TYPE
)
FROM product ct FOR XML PATH('products')
```

The easiest way to filter is to add condition in both query and sub-query:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*) AS '@count',
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM product c1 
    WHERE c1.status = 1 AND ......
    FOR XML PATH('product'), TYPE
)
FROM product ct 
WHERE ct.status = 1 AND ......
FOR XML PATH('products')
```

Or use temp-table:

```
SELECT *
INTO #Temp
FROM product c1
WHERE c1.status = 1 AND ......


SELECT 
COUNT(*) AS '@count',
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM #Temp c1 
    FOR XML PATH('product'), TYPE
)
FROM #Temp ct 
FOR XML PATH('products')
```

Comment: actually i dont want all products, i have some conditions, so i edited the question.

Comment: thank you, so that means i need to add conditions to both query and subquery. Isn't it possible to achieve this writing conditions only one time. Cause the query i gave is example, my actual query is very long.

Comment: @doganhisa possible, but with temp-table

Comment: @doganhisa hi, can you accept my answer or I should improve it?